# Large memory usage for sqlite3

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, sqlite

I have been using sqlite3 in my python2 project to speed up some tasks while leaving a small memory footprint. However, I have stumbled upon a curious issue where using the `ORDER BY` clause in a database query consumes lots of RAM memory. I'm really not sure about the cause and how to circumvent this issue. I have found nothing in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for sqlite3. An example follows.

I can create a simple table and insert some dummy data

```
import sqlite3
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

con = sqlite3.connect("order_mem.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE ordertest (idx INT, slice INT, seq TEXT)")

def load_data():

    for i in range(20):
        for p in xrange(50000):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO ordertest VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (p, i, "A" * 1000))
```

If I want to fetch the data using a normal or ordered query, I get wildly different memory usages.

Unordered:

```
def iterate_unordered():

    for i in cur.execute("SELECT idx, seq FROM ordertest"):
        pass

load_data()
mem_usage = memory_usage(iterate_unordered)
print(max(mem_usage))
# 33.99609375
```

Ordered:

```
def iterate_ordered():

    for i in cur.execute("SELECT idx, seq FROM ordertest ORDER BY slice"):

        pass

load_data()
mem_usage = memory_usage(iterate_ordered)
print(max(mem_usage))
# 1028.78515625
```

Is there a way to perform this ordered query without grabbing so much memory?

EDIT: As per CL. answer, creating an index on the column that will be sorted greatly reduces RAM consumption during the sorting of that column. For comparative purposes, the result with the index:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE ordertest (idx INT, slice INT, seq TEXT)")
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX test ON ordertest(slice)")

def iterate_ordered():

    for i in cur.execute("SELECT idx, slice, seq FROM ordertest ORDER BY slice"):
        pass

load_data()

mem_usage = memory_usage(iterate_ordered)
print(max(mem_usage))
#33.9296875
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite computes result rows on demand. But when you use ORDER BY, the database must sort all rows and keep that temporary list in memory.

To avoid the sorting, you have to keep a sorted list in the database, i.e., create an index on the `slice` column. (It is important not only that the rows are actually sorted, but that the query optimizer is able to prove that they are sorted.)

Comment: Neat! Since I do not require the index to be unique, this is perfect